# Call a function inside a function and return a value

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to call a function on click a button, execute some code like adding an item to a database and also having access to a variable that was created in that function?

For example,

```
const handleAddToDb = () => {
   let id = 123423r //note the ID is auto generated each time this function is called
   addToDb()
   return id
}
<button onClick={()=> {
  handleAddToDb()
}}>Click</button>
console.log(id???)   // any idea how to achieve this?
```

Comment: I think you can try to do this `const id = handleAddToDb()`

Comment: One way to achieve this is to store the return value of the function in a global variable(assuming you are using vanilla JS).

Comment: Does this button  have the id? Do you have multiple buttons?  Are you just trying to reference the button the user clicked?

Comment: each time the button is called, the ID is randomized

Comment: also this function is stored in a js file that contians many functions and it is being imported in each component that it is needed

Answer (score 1):

```html
<body>
    <button onclick="
            handleAddToDb()
    ">
    Click me
    </button>
</body>
<script>
    // let id is a global variable
    let id = 10;
    const handleAddToDb = () => {
        addToDb()
        console.log(id)
    }
    function addToDb(){
        id++;
    }
    console.log(id)    // any idea how to achieve this?
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have your click handler return the id (as you're doing) and assign it to a variable that's accessible in your outer scope.

You could also establish a "store" that's responsible for managing all of the data, including doing the add and keeping track of the new id. See snippet below for a very skeletal example of how two separate buttons can access the same data using this approach.

```js
const addButton = document.getElementById('add');
const logButton = document.getElementById('log');

class Store {
  lastId = 0;
  
  add() {
    // do whatever you need to do.
    // increment and return the id.
    return this.lastId++;
  }
}

const store = new Store();

addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  store.add();
  console.log(store.lastId);
})

logButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log(store.lastId);
})
```

```html
<button id="add">Add</button>

<button id="log">Log Last Id</button>
```